# "Attachment Unavailable" on messages sent with FB.ui

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, facebook-ui

I'm trying to include a link and an image in messages I'm sending with the use of FB.ui({method: "send"});

docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/

Note that I've seen [this accepted answer](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7385141/facebook-attachment-unavailable-error-when-using-the-send-button) but it doesn't address my question.

Sometimes the recipient can see the image and link and other times they see this:

---

[image]

---

Any idea what may cause this? The image is hosted on AWS CloudFront and is accessible via HTTP and HTTPS.

Comment: Got same error, answered here http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7385141/facebook-attachment-unavailable-error-when-using-the-send-button/8149779#8149779

Comment: Thanks, but that's not the answer. This only happens for some users. A related question from a Facebook user:  https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=1513310

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem where "Attachment Unavailable" happened when the user that clicked the send button had set their Default Privacy to Custom and wasn't making things visible to Friends or better. The sender could view the attachment in their own messages, but the recipient got the "Attachment Unavailable" error.

Comment: Yes -- that's what our investigation here has concluded. Specifically,  users won't get the attachment if the sender has A) put the recipient on their 'Restricted' list (screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/NgXtO.png ), or B) they've closed their Wall (so others can't post on it). There may be other scenarios that also don't work but I'm not sure.